# Why is there performance difference in .NET Target framework(3.5 and 4) while using oleDB to export data to excel?

Tags: c#, oledb

I am working on a project which involves writing data to excel file using oleDB. When I use .NET Framework 3.5 client Profile as Target framework I get the whole process  completed in 2-3 seconds, but setting the Target framework as .NET Framework 4 doubles the processing time that is, it now takes 5-6 seconds and I have no clue why this is happening.

Comment: Hi @naveen if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/287197 by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't matter which .net framework you are using what matters is which version of  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel you are using, there are two versions of  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, one is 14.0 and 2nd is 12.0, you can switch to any version and recheck if problem is resolved, You need to remove any previous references of  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel by clicking on references tab in solution explorer, and then add new reference by right clicking on your project and add reference and in .net tab try to serach Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.

Comment: First I'm using oleDB not interop, Second this behavior is for same connection string.